# Does Object.values returned the 'values` in order as they were defined in the object

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given I have a object like ..

```
const payload = {
    prop0: 'a',
    prop1: 'b',
    prop2: 'c',
    prop3: 'd',
    prop4: 'e'
};
```

On doing this `[...Object.values(payload)]`

Will it always return

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
```

Or can in some conditions the order be different like `['b', 'c', 'a', 'e', 'd']`

Comment: JavaScript objects never guarantee the order of the keys, but you can definitely sort it to that

Comment: @SterlingArcher - Yes, they do. Have done for nearly four years. (**Don't** read that as an endorsement of anyone actually **using** the order. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's good to know that's been changed, but the dupe that was linked specifies that in the answers it seems. Any reason you re-opened this to answer it instead of adding more relevant details to the duplicate?

Comment: @SterlingArcher - Because my brain misfired and I thought the answer for `Object.values` was different from the answer for `for-in`, which is what the answers there focus on. But I'm wrong. If you can re-dupehammer, that'd be great.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder no worries, happens to me a lot too! :) I don't have a gold badge or remaining close votes, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties is the proper, up to date duplicate

Comment: @Adeel - No, you can't rely on the order of `Object.values`. It uses the spec's [EnumerableOwnPropertyNames](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-enumerableownpropertynames) operation. Although that uses [[OwnPropertyKeys]], which would provide ES2015 order, it explicitly then says that the order should be rearranged to whatever implementation-dependent order `for-in` (and such) use. That order is not defined.

Comment: @SterlingArcher - Hey, it let me dupehammer. I didn't think you could dupehammer after being the one who reopened. TIL.

Comment: Thank you for the help guys :) You guys are awesome.

Comment: @AdeelImran anytime! Sorry it's a dupe, but there's excellent information in there that should help you. Feel free to go to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript if you have more questions! I'm there, so you can ping me if you want

Comment: Great, again thank you so much!